# What is the particular solution given $y=4$ and $x=3$ for the equation: $xy \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^3-x}{1-\sqrt y}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I am almost done solving this question, however, I am stuck on the integration. This is my work; the answer is:
$$\int\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{{2y^{5/2}}}{5}\right)dy=\int \left(x^2-x\right)dx$$
and I have to integrate it. I would think that the $-x$ would equal to $\frac{-x^2}{2}$ but the answer on the back of my book is: $\displaystyle \frac{y^2}{2} - \frac{2}{5} y^{5/2} =\frac{x^3}{3}-x-\frac{54}{5}$

What is the particular solution given $y=4$ and $x=3$?

**My Solution**
$$\left(xy\right) \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^3-x}{1-\sqrt y}$$
$$y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{x^3-x}{1-\sqrt{y}}\\
y(1-\sqrt y)\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot (x^3-x)\\
\int (y-y^\frac{3}{2}) \frac{dy}{dx}=\int{x^2-x}\\=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{2y^{5/2}}{5}=\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2}{2}+c\\
\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{2y^{5/2}}{5}-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}=c$$

Comment: There seems a mistake in editing? The book answer that you wrote before the edit was reading different which is the answer I get. Can you confirm?

Comment: Sorry, I edited best I could. There were some vocabulary mistakes so I must have gotten confused.

Comment: @Math Lover thats correct dont woory i fixed it

Comment: thank you @Obsessive Integer for editing it.

Comment: @maryjames Don't mention it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you have to solve the equation:
$$\left(xy\right) \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^3-x}{1-\sqrt y}$$
The first step is to move things around, which you did properly.
$$y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{x^3-x}{1-\sqrt{y}}$$

Now we can move the $dx$ to the other side and write the equation as,

$$y(1-\sqrt y)dy=\frac{1}{x}\cdot (x^3-x)dx$$
Simplifying and adding in the integration,
$$\int \left(y-y^\frac{3}{2}\right)dy= \int(x^2-1)dx$$

So, integrating both sides, we have,
$$\frac{y^{1+1}}{(1+1)}-\frac{y^{\frac{3}{2}+1}}{\left(\frac{3}{2}+1\right)}=\frac{x^{2+1}}{(2+1)}-x+C\\
\frac{1}{2}y^2-\frac{2}{5}y^{\frac{5}{2}}=\frac{1}{3}x^3-x+C$$

Finally, plugging in $y=4$ and $x=3$, we have,
$$\frac{1}{2}(4)^2-\frac{2}{5}(4)^{\frac{5}{2}}=\frac{1}{3}(3)^3-3+C\\
-\frac{24}{5}=6+C\\ C=-\frac{54}{5}$$ or, we can make it a little cleaner by saying that there is some other constant, say $C_1$, such that, $$C_{1}=\frac{54}{5}$$

Answer (score 2):

The ODE is $$\displaystyle \small xy\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^3-x}{1- \sqrt y},$$ which can be rewritten as

$$\displaystyle \small (y-y^{3/2}) \ dy  = (x^2-1) \ dx. \ $$ This is the step where you have a mistake! By integrating both sides we get:

$$\displaystyle \small \frac{y^2}{2} - \frac{2}{5} y^{5/2} = \frac{x^3}{3} - x + C,$$

Now, plug in $\small y = 4, x = 3$ and so you'll get $\small C = \displaystyle - \frac{54}{5}$.